# android: how to post status on facebook

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I want to update status of user along with location of user in android. I have latitude, longitude and name of the location.
I have already updated status but couldn't figure out how to post it along with location.

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

            Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                    Log.d("Checkin", response.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(context, response.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            };
            if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
                Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(session,
                        "Posting from my fyp", null, null, callback)
                        .executeAsync();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can do this using latest Facebook SDK:

```
Location location = new Location("provider");
location.setLatitude(13.1234);
location.setLongitude(13.1234);

final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
Request placesSearchRequest = Request.newPlacesSearchRequest(session, location, 100, 
        1, "", 
        new GraphPlaceListCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(List<GraphPlace> places, Response response) {
            Request statusUpdateRequest = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(session, "Hell Yea :P #fyp #success #viaCheckinApp", 
                            places.get(0), null, new Callback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                    debug("response of posting checkin to facebook: " + response.toString());                               
                                }
                            });
                    statusUpdateRequest.executeAsync();
                }
            });

    placesSearchRequest.executeAsync();
```